# 2 text box with validation of custom format and input, and comparing both data VB2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am kinda stuck with this scenario!
I need to create 2 text box with same format of data "3XYZ-02-01-ABC-001" and Then need to compare only "3XYZ-02-01-ABC" with popup text when not matches.

I using VB2010 and creating it in winform,

Unable to use RegEX, don't know why? any solution for that?
Any masked textbox solution , will help , greatly appreciate.
Its a bit of challenge!

Thanks

Comment: `\d[a-z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{3}-\d{3}|\d[a-z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{3}` -- sorry updated.  This should match both conditions. If you need the result, can do `(\d[a-z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{3}-\d{3})|(\d[a-z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{3})` .  You could also use grouping and special conditions in .NET regex, but havn't played enough with that yet to give advice.

Comment: I added a solution which does the test for you and returns a boolean (true/false) response.  Havn't tested it so if the boolean response is backwards, just add a `^` as the first character in the first regex line.

Answer (score 0):

To validate (boolean) without returning the string, this will check both conditions.

```
public function ValidateCode(Code as string) as boolean
   Dim test As String = ""

   ' The longer code check
   test = "\d[a-z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{3}-\d{3}"

   ' The regex OR operator
   test = test & "|"

   ' The shorter code check
   test = test & "\d[a-z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-[a-z]{3}"

   ' Perform regex test and return the boolean
   return Regex.IsMatch( Code, test )
end function
```